# Ajax script to get chat messages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to AJAX, and I'm trying to get some messages from a database for a shoutbox. This is my AJAX script:

```
var chatUpdate = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/getChat",
        success: function(data) {
            // do something with "data"
            if (data.length > 0) {
                var page = $(data);
                var time = page.find('#time').val();
                console.log(time);
                var now = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
                if(now >= time){
                var statusText = page.find('#msg').val();
                console.log(statusText);
                $("#chatTable").append(statusText);
            }
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
};

setInterval(chatUpdate, 25000);
```

and what PHP does after it gets the data:

```
echo "<div id='msg'><tr><td>" .$row['username']. "<hr style='margin:0; padding: 0;' />" .$row['msg']. "</td></tr></div> <div id='time'>".$row['time']."</div>";
```

but, in the console it says that neither statusText or time have a value. What would be causing this, because there's definitely data in the database.

Comment: What is `page.find('#msg')` returning? Log it and see if it's null. If it's null then something is messed up.

Comment: @JamesSpence Logging statusText should log that, shouldn't it?

Comment: Try logging the element itself, not its value.

Comment: `div`s don't have a `value` attribute, so `page.find('#time').val();`/`page.find('#msg').val()` will return null. Try using `.text()` or `.html()`

Comment: @Sean That worked. If I stored the last messages ID in a variable, and passed it along to the function each time, do you think that it would stop the same message from repeating over and over

Comment: Yes. If you send the ID as parameter to your url, then you could use it to select only messages after that ID.

Comment: @Sean On more question, when I use `.html()` it removes the `<tr><td>` and respective closing tags, but keeps the `<strong>` tags.